# SQL: join within same table with different 'where' clause

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Ok, so the problem I'm facing is this, I have a table with 3 columns : ID, Key and Value.

```
ID | Key | Value
================
1  |  1  |  ab
1  |  2  |  cd
1  |  3  |  ef
2  |  1  |  gh
2  |  2  |  ij
2  |  3  |  kl
```

Now I want to select the value of Keys 1 & 3 for all IDs, the return should be like this

```
ID |  1  | 2
================
1  |  ab |  ef
2  |  gh |  kl
```

So per ID 1 row containing the Values for Keys 1 & 3.

I tried using 'join' but since I need to use multiple where clauses I can't figure out how to get this to work ..

Comment: why is the ID not unique? is this a relation table?

Comment: The ID is a foreign key to a different table

Comment: What you probably want is often called a pivot table.  But the implementation depends on which database server you're using (because the answer is often procedural, not just a single Select).

Comment: There's a slight typo in what the return should look like, the second row should be `2 | gh | kl`.  Made it a bit confusing what you were asking for at first.

Comment: Ah... don't you love the smell of EAV designs in the morning...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Oracle 8i+, use:

```
  SELECT t.id,
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.key = 1 THEN t.value ELSE NULL END) AS "1",
         MAX(CASE WHEN t.key = 2 THEN t.value ELSE NULL END) AS "2"
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.id
```

For Oracle versions prior, swap the CASE out for [DECODE syntax](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php).  Oracle didn't add the PIVOT syntax until 11g.

Comment: @Vincent Malgrat: Thx, didn't know CASE was supported that early.

Comment: hmm keeping getting an error 'missing left parenthesis' using this code. There doesn't seem to be anything missing though ..

Comment: @Pmarcoen: Check the aggregate function - make sure the CASE statement is entirely inside it.

Comment: Got this one to work now as well, indeed, much faster, sorry for premature acceptance :)

Comment: @Pmarcoen: AFAIK, you should be able to change the accepted answer to this one. My answer was only an alternative for when pivots are not available.

Answer (score 1):

Without using pivot queries, you could also join with a subquery, as follows:

```
SELECT     t.id, MAX(key_1.value) AS '1', MAX(key_3.value) AS '2'
FROM       tb t
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, value FROM tb WHERE `key` = 1) key_1 ON (key_1.id = t.id)
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, value FROM tb WHERE `key` = 3) key_3 ON (key_3.id = t.id)
GROUP BY   t.id;
```

Test Case (in MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE tb (`id` int, `key` int, `value` char(2));
INSERT INTO tb VALUES (1, 1, 'ab');
INSERT INTO tb VALUES (1, 2, 'cd');
INSERT INTO tb VALUES (1, 3, 'ef');
INSERT INTO tb VALUES (2, 1, 'gh');
INSERT INTO tb VALUES (2, 2, 'ij');
INSERT INTO tb VALUES (2, 3, 'kl');
```

Result:

```
+------+------+------+
| id   | 1    | 2    |
+------+------+------+
|    1 | ab   | ef   |
|    2 | gh   | kl   |
+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just do three queries?

If I understand you correctly, your going to have to use a union join.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, VALUE AS v1, S.v2
FROM TABLE
WHERE KEY = 1
JOIN (SELECT ID, VALUE AS v2 FROM TABLE WHERE Key =3) AS S ON TABLE.ID = S.ID
```

If you need more, add a join for each where...